# Можно ли сделать замены в строке без сторонних библиотек и без циклов в одну строчку?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, оптимизация, замена

У меня есть строка вида:

```
"Hello World!?,."
```

Надо удалить все символы пунктуации, то есть в результате должно остаться просто:

```
"Hello World"
```

Можно ли это все оформить в одну строчку, без циклов и *сторонних* библиотек?

---

PS Без *сторонних* библиотек, это значит используя только модули стандартной библиотеки, т.е. те, которые не нужно дополнительно устанавливать.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В одну строку без циклов (явных или неявных) и без использования модулей:

```
In [274]: text = "Hello World!?,."

In [275]: res = text.translate(str.maketrans("", "", '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'))

In [276]: res
Out[276]: 'Hello World'
```

PS [ссылка на документацию по методу `str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)

---

**UPD:** если можно использовать модули из стандартной библиотеки, тогда символы пунктуации лучше взять из `string`:

```
from string import punctuation as punct

res = text.translate(str.maketrans("", "", punct))
```

---

С использованием регулярных выражений:

```
import re

res = re.sub(r"[^\w\s]", "", text)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, очень полезные, теперь пойду разберусь с новым для меня методом translate

Comment: Спасибо за документацию

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> test = "Hello World!?,."
>>> test
'Hello World!?,.'
```

в python еще и не такое можно в одну строчку:

```
>>> new = ''.join(s for s in w if s not in '!?,.')
>>> new
'Hello World'
```

упс, тут есть цикл... хотя, под капотом, он будет во всех реализациях

Comment: Квадратные скобки излишние.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, действительно просто, но надеялся на магию питона, так сказать.

Answer (score 3):

С использованием встроенных библиотек:

```py
import string
from functools import reduce

src = "Hello World!?,."

final = reduce(
    lambda acc, x: acc.replace(x, ''),
    string.punctuation,
    src
)

print(final)
```

Можно сделать короче с регулярками, но мне лень вспоминать.